# Need help on FastAGI when playing recording

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk, fastagi

I've been playing Asterisk `FastAGI()` for a while until I've meet this problem.

So I have an app that uses `FastAGI()`. I don't have a problem playing a file or a swift message in it. But if two calls comes in and I play a message for both channels. It won't play simultaneously. It only plays on the first call that answers it and then after the message is played to the first one it then play on the second one. So I kinda wanted to play the message/recording for both of them on the same time or at least not to wait for the other one to finish.

Your reply is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It have no any relation to FastAGI.

Without dialplan no way say what you dooing wrong, but you always can use conference to play one message to difference persons in same time.

Comment: But I need to get a response from the caller. Such as digit pressed.

Comment: So you have sync it yourself or hire other person who can understand what you dooing and fix it. I never noticed problem you described, i work with asterisk 10 years every day. Put your dialplan or describe more carefully what you want.

Comment: Hi arheops, Thank you for your reply.
So I think I won't have this kind of issue if doing it on dialplan. Sorry for not being clear, but this is an app that were building using Asterisk.Net library to communicate with Asterisk Server.

Comment: do on asterisk: "agi set debug on "  after that call, show output. i am sorry, no way guess what is issue.